# CORS strange behaviour with trailing slash using React and Flask API

Tags: reactjs, flask, cors, slash, trailing-slash

I'm currently building an application with React and a Flask API and I got some CORS errors I don't understand :

I've got an endpoint like this :

```py
@app.route('/home/', methods=['GET'])
def home():
    response = Response(
        json.dumps(
            get_data()
        ),
        mimetype='application/json'
    )
    response.headers.add("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*")
    return response
```

If I call this endpoint from react like this, everything works fine:

```js
fetch('http://localhost:8080/home/')
            .then(res => res.json())
            .then((data) => {
                setData(data)
            })
            .catch(console.log)
```

However, if I set my route as `'/home'` in my Flask API (no trailing slash) and I call it using `fetch('http://localhost:8080/home)'` I got a CORS error: `Access to fetch at 'http://localhost:8080/home' from origin 'http://localhost:3000' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.`

Although it's not a big issue for my project, I would like to understand what this trailing slash change...

Thanks,

Answer (score 6):

`/home` and `/home/` are different routes to flask, but for routes with a trailing slash it will automatically do a redirect when accessing the route with a trailing slash.

So when your app accesses `/home` flask returns a redirect to `/home/` but without the CORS-Header. This leads to the error you are seeing.

See also [Flask Documentation](https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/2.0.x/quickstart/#unique-urls-redirection-behavior)

Comment: I see but in the case that the flask route is '/home' and react fetches '/home' there is no need to redirect right? So why do I got an error in this scenario?

Comment: Honestly I don't know. Maybe you can check if your flask app is returning the correct responses by pressing F12 in your browser, then click on the "Network" tab. Then after visiting '/home' you can look at the http responses your app is sending.